# VB.Net Calculating values using GridView bound fields and outputting value to another field

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview, boundfield

Within a GridView is it possible, using the output of two or more asp BoundFields, 
to calculate a value and then output this in it's own field?

eg calculating % from two bound fields:

```
Amount    Total    % (calculated field from Amount / Total * 100)
137       69       50.4
```

or is it better to generate this calculation using SQL and output the result to it's own BoundField?

Comment: I'd probably do it in the SQL for sheer convenience - otherwise you'd be repeating the work by looping through the gridview and calculating for each row.

Comment: Good call Tim, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TemplateField` instead of the `BoundField`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Calculation">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server" 
                     Text='<% ((Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Amount"))/Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("Total")))*Convert.ToDecimal(100)).ToString() %>' >  
        </asp:TextBox>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```